# How to avoid saying "gstring"?

Tags: groovy, gstring

I am picking up Groovy. The language is fine. But I have a non-technical problem. One of the classes is called GString. In some context, it can be misleading. And mentioning it is not very appropriate in the office, especially when some non-technical female colleagues are around.

I guess this is not enough to justify renaming the class in the language. So how should I avoid saying "GString" when I want to say GString?

Comment: I... this... just......

Answer (score 16):

Personally, I think you should just say "GString" and use the confusion and subsequent explanation to begin conversations with the non-technical female colleagues.

Comment: that works, until they start reporting you to your manager for using sexual innuendo in the workplace ...

Comment: absolutely brilliant answer!!

Comment: @phalacee But then you can explain to your manager what GString is, and get Groovy adopted everywhere...

Comment: @Rich: +10 points if you can get your manager on side :D

Comment: @phalacee Sadly I work in France - I'm not sure they'd get it (or mind)

Comment: I'm sure there's a market for a T-shirt or something saying "Groovy Programmers do it in GStrings".

Answer (score 5):

Other languages call these kind of strings with placeholders "interpolated strings", so you can use that, or potentially just call them "Groovy String".

Answer (score 3):

what does the G stand for? If it's Groovy, then call it GroovyString, or even GrooveString ... or guhString ... as in the lower-case sound of 'G'

Answer (score 2):

I would pronounce it "GiString".

Answer (score 1):

Say Gstring a lot. You female colleages may start to notice you.